# REGEXP_CONTAINS not recognized

Tags: google-bigquery

Happy new years, stackoverflow!

I am trying to use some regex functions in bigquery but some of them return error as if I have the name wrong.

```
SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, r'^abc$') FROM [tablename]

Query Failed
Error: 2.24 - 2.26: Unrecognized function regexp_contains
```

Where as if I do a similar regex function, the function text in the editor changes color and the query works.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'^abc$') FROM [tablename]
```

It should work since it's documented in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery Legacy SQL and Standard SQL support different set of regular expression functions
Legacy SQL [Regular Expression Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#regularexpressionfunctions):
`REGEXP_MATCH`, `REGEXP_EXTRACT` and `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Standard SQL [Regular Expression Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains):
`REGEXP_CONTAINS`, `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` and `REGEXP_REPLACE`

So, in your case just make sure you use proper BigQuery SQL [dialect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, r'^abc$') FROM [tablename]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is frustrating because I noticed the legacy vs standard earlier when I was doing something else...